# Scheme filter but the result list contains indices not values

Tags: scheme, racket

Is there any easy way to create a kind of filter with the outcome the indices instead of values?

for example:

```
'(#true #false #true) -> '(0 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom filter procedure that returns a list of indices for elements of a list where a predicate produces a true value, as such:

```
(define (filtr pred lst)
  (for/list ([i lst]
             [n (in-naturals)]
             #:when (pred i))
    n))
```

For example,

```
> (filtr number? '(1 2 3 a b c 8 d 19 e f))
'(0 1 2 6 8)
> (filtr (lambda (x) (and x)) '(#true #false #true))
'(0 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is a way to do it; there's many ways to do it. Here's one way.

```
(define (func xs)
  (let loop ((index 0) (xs xs))
    (cond ((empty? xs) empty)
          ((car xs) (cons index (loop (add1 index) (cdr xs))))
          (else (loop (add1 index) (cdr xs))))))

(func '(#true #false #true #false #false #true #true))
;; => '(0 2 5 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Racket has a function for this (Not sure if it was present when this question was asked) - [`indexes-where`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._indexes-where%29%29), in `racket/list`.

Example:

```lisp
> (indexes-where '(1 2 0 3 0 4) zero?)
'(2 4)
```